# How do I disable Label Text on Y-Axis but keep the gridlines in Chart.js 2.6?

Tags: javascript, charts, drawing, chart.js2

Using Chart.js 2.6 trying to configure the graph to have grid lines but no labels on Y Axis.  Here's my config options:

```
var wowOptions = {
    scaleBeginAtZero: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scaleStartValue: -50,
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            gridLines: {
                display: false,
                offsetGridLines: true,
                zeroLineColor: "red"
            },
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 4,
                autoSkip: true
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            display: false,
            gridLines: {
                display: true,
                offsetGridLines: false,
                drawOnChartArea: true,
                drawBorder: false

            }
        }]

    }
```

When I set display: false it disables both grid lines and the labels on the Y Axis:
[image: Lost gridlines, please come back!]

When I set display: true for yAxes I see both the gridLines and labels:

I'm trying to loose the label -50, 0, 50, 100 but keep the gridLines. Is there a way to do this?

[image: have grid lines but want to lose labels]

Thanks in advance, 
Griff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting `display: false` for the y-axis itself, while you need to set it for y-axis­*'s* ticks, like so ...

```
options: {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            display: false
         }
      }]
   },
   ...
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
      datasets: [{
         label: '# of Votes',
         data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 5]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               display: false
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Awesome, that was it!